# Error "Attempt to create a HVM guest on a non-VT/AMDV platform" when Intel VT-d is enabled in BIOS

Tags: intel, xen

I'm installing XEN on an older Vernonia server with a [Cloverdale VT-d compatible](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/30702/intel-xeon-processor-x5365-8m-cache-3-00-ghz-1333-mhz-fsb.html) CPU, either an [S5000XVNSATAR](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/46538/intel-workstation-board-s5000xvnsatar.html) or [S5000XVNSASR](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/46542/intel-workstation-board-s5000xvnsasr.html), a [2006 design](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5000xvn/sb/418519_d66403_006_s5000xvn_tps_r1_5.pdf) with [some documentation still available](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5000xvn/sb/d36222004_s5000xvn_user_guide.pdf). This problem is not found in the Intel [Community Support Forum](https://forums.intel.com/s/global-search/vernonia?language=en_US) [[alternate search]](https://forums.intel.com/s/global-search/s5000xvn?language=en_US).

```
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Intel
    Product Name: S5000XVN
    Version: Not Specified
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
```

I've verified `Intel VT-d` is `enabled` in BIOS

I've installed `xen-system-amd64`, cloned over an existing (functional) XEN VM logical volume, and added the (modified) server.cfg file.

However when I try to start the VM, I get ...

```
root@XENserver:/etc/xen# xl create server.cfg 
Parsing config from server.cfg
WARNING: ignoring device_model directive.
WARNING: Use "device_model_override" instead if you really want a non-default device_model
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:478:libxl__domain_make: domain creation fail
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:745:initiate_domain_create: cannot make domain: -3
libxl: error: libxl.c:1409:libxl__destroy_domid: non-existant domain -1
libxl: error: libxl.c:1373:domain_destroy_callback: unable to destroy guest with domid 4294967295
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1328:domcreate_destruction_cb: unable to destroy domain 4294967295 following failed creation

root@XENserver:/etc/xen# xl dmesg
(XEN) Dom0 has maximum 8 VCPUs
(XEN) Scrubbing Free RAM: .done.
(XEN) Initial low memory virq threshold set at 0x4000 pages.
(XEN) Std. Loglevel: Errors and warnings
(XEN) Guest Loglevel: Nothing (Rate-limited: Errors and warnings)
(XEN) Xen is relinquishing VGA console.
(XEN) *** Serial input -> DOM0 (type 'CTRL-a' three times to switch input to Xen)
(XEN) Freed 264kB init memory.
(XEN) hvm.c:557:d0 Attempt to create a HVM guest on a non-VT/AMDV platform.
(XEN) hvm.c:557:d0 Attempt to create a HVM guest on a non-VT/AMDV platform.

root@XENserver:/etc/xen# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              11
CPU MHz:               2992.548
BogoMIPS:              5985.09
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   none
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

**SERVER.CFG**

```
device_model = '/usr/lib/xen-4.0/bin/qemu-dm'
builder = 'hvm'
memory      = '8192'
vcpus       = '2'
disk        = [
                    'phy:/dev/vg-xen/server-disk,ioemu:hda,w',
                        'file:/mnt/share/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso,hdc:cdrom,r'

              ]

name        = 'i61smbadb'
vif         = [ 'mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' ]

on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'

boot            = 'dc'

# For vnc connectivity
sdl=0
vnc=1
vncconsole=9
vncdisplay=9 # Sets the port to 5909
vnclisten   = '141.3.88.11'
vncpasswd='match wine signature'
stdvga=0
serial='pty'
usbdevice='tablet'
```

Comment: Sadly, this is a 13 year old design, long ago discontinued. I'd suggest replicating this post in the Intel Community Forum at https://forums.intel.com/s/global-search/s5000xvn?language=en_US